# Includ mako file once page is loaded

Tags: performance, mako

I have a mako file included into a HTML template that takes time to load.

I want to load it only when the rest of the page is fully loaded.

Let's consider this html template fragment:

```
...
<section> 
<%include file="widget.html"/>
</section>
...
```

I want the line `<%include file...`, to be read by the browser only when all the rest of page is loaded.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't read the `<%include...`—it's interpreted by the server before being sent to the browser.

You could have an `onload` JavaScript call that makes an AJAX request for "widget.html" and puts it in your page.